# typescript - class as interface when constructor is used

Tags: typescript

If I have a class of this form:

```
class MyClass {
   a: string  
}
```

and then I define a variable:

```
let obj: MyClass = { a: 2 }
```

I'm getting a Typescript error, as expected, because 2 is not a string. However, if `MyClass` contains a constructor:

```
class MyClass {
   constructor(a: string) {
   }
}
```

Then Typescript remains silent after the same variable declaration. Is there a way to use a constructor and still use the class as interface? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript remains silent because the second example of `MyClass` doesn't define any member variable for `a`, only a constructor argument. You'll still have to declare the member variable in order for it to be checked:

```
class MyClass {
  a: string

  constructor(a: string) {
    this.a = a // assign to self as an example
  }
}
```

However, TS gives some nice syntactic sugar for this. If you put an access visibility keyword like `public`, `private` or `protected` in front of the constructor argument, typescript will automatically assign it for you, with that level of visibility. So this becomes equivalent to the above, which is what I think you might've wanted to do here.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(public a: string) {}
}
```

Comment: Excellent, the public modifier is the missing part, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`let obj: MyClass = { a: 2 }`

You are giving the class the integer 2.

What you're trying to do is

```
let obj: MyClass = { a: '2' }
```

The other comment explained it pretty well.